# Convert SQL Server trigger into oracle trigger

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, database-migration, database-trigger

I am trying to convert the SQL Server trigger shown below to an Oracle trigger but I get compile time errors.

SQL Server trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[triggerName]   
ON [dbo].[table] 
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted) -- UPDATE
    BEGIN
        IF NOT (UPDATE (lastupdated))  
        BEGIN  
            UPDATE [table] 
            SET lastupdated = GETUTCDATE() 
            WHERE EventKey IN (SELECT EventKey FROM inserted);

            INSERT INTO table2 ([EventKey], [ProgramKey], [ProgramActivityKey],
                                [ParentEventKey], [ComplianceDate],
                                [CycleNumber], [Priority], [WorkPolygonKey],
                                [Shape], [IsCompleted], [IsFieldException],
                                [CompletedDate], [DueDate],
                                [IsSystemException], [FromDate], [ToDate],
                                [CrewKey], [UserKey], [UserId])
                (SELECT
                     e.[EventKey], [ProgramKey], [ProgramActivityKey],
                     [ParentEventKey], [ComplianceDate],
                     [CycleNumber], [Priority], [WorkPolygonKey],
                     [Shape], [IsCompleted], [IsFieldException],
                     [CompletedDate], [DueDate], 
                     [IsSystemException], [lastupdated], GETUTCDATE(),
                     [CrewKey], w.[UserKey], [UserId]
                 FROM
                     deleted e 
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     table3 w ON e.EventKey = w.EventKey 
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     [table4] u ON u.UserKey = w.UserKey);
        END;
    END;
    ELSE 
    BEGIN -- INSERT
        UPDATE [table] 
        SET lastupdated = GETUTCDATE() 
        WHERE EventKey IN (SELECT EventKey FROM inserted);
    END
END
```

Converted Oracle trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_lastModified AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE  ON  Event 
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
v_userKey NUMBER;
v_eventKey NUMBER;

BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    IF UPDATING THEN--if exists (select * from deleted) -- UPDATE  
            IF NOT UPDATING ('lastupdated') THEN

        UPDATE Event SET lastupdated = SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(SYSTIMESTAMP) WHERE EventKey = :NEW.EventKey;

        SELECT userkey INTO v_userKey FROM WorkAssignment w WHERE w.EventKey = :OLD.EventKey LEFT JOIN User_ u ON u.UserKey = w.UserKey;

            INSERT INTO EventHistory VALUES (:OLD.EventKey,
                                                    :OLD.ProgramKey,
                                                    :OLD.ProgramActivityKey,
                                                    :OLD.ParentEventKey,
                                                    :OLD.ComplianceDate,
                                                    :OLD.CycleNumber,
                                                    :OLD.Priority,
                                                    :OLD.WorkPolygonKey,
                                                    :OLD.Shape,
                                                    :OLD.IsCompleted,
                                                    :OLD.IsFieldException,
                                                    :OLD.CompletedDate,
                                                    :OLD.DueDate,
                                                    :OLD.IsSystemException,
                                                    :OLD.FromDate,
                                                    SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(SYSTIMESTAMP),
                                                    :OLD.CrewKey,
                                                    v_userKey,
                                                    :OLD.UserId);           
      END IF;
    ELSE
            UPDATE Event SET lastupdated = SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(SYSTIMESTAMP) WHERE  EventKey = :NEW.EventKey;
  END IF;    
END;
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Error(13,9): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(13,94): PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
Error(29,14): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.FROMDATE'
Error(31,14): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.CREWKEY'
Error(33,14): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.USERID'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invalid syntax is in this SELECT; I fixed it:

```
 SELECT userkey
   INTO v_userKey
   FROM WorkAssignment w LEFT JOIN User_ u ON u.UserKey = w.UserKey
  WHERE w.EventKey = :OLD.EventKey;
```

Also, it seems that you are performing `UPDATE Event` in any case, so - maybe you should move it out of the `IF-THEN-ELSE`.

Comment: After adding changes based on your comments i am still getting binding error:Error(32,14): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.FROMDATE'
Error(34,14): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.CREWKEY'
Error(36,14): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.USERID'

Comment: In order for this to work, those columns (FROMDATE, CREWKEY, USERID) must exist in the EVENT table. Do they?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I really appreciate it.